# Symfony 2 - ways to reduce redundant code

Tags: php, symfony

I'm writing a simple Symfony2 web application. I realised that almost every controller in my application does the same operations, but on a different object. I'm talkin about standard CRUD operations: creating, reading, updating and deleting. I will use 'delete' operation as an example

Example:

```
class CustomerController {
/**
 * @Route("/customer")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request){
    $rep =this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer');

    $customerId = $request->get('id');
    if ($customerId != null) {
        $rep->delete($customerId);
    } else {
        $rep->deleteAll();
    }
    $response = new Response(null, Response::HTTP_OK);
    return $response;
}
}

class ProductController {
/**
 * @Route("/product")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request){
    $rep =this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');

    $productId = $request->get('id');
    if ($productId != null) {
        $rep->delete($productId);
    } else {
        $rep->deleteAll();
    }
    $response = new Response(null, Response::HTTP_OK);
    return $response;
}
}

class CompanyController {
/**
 * @Route("/company")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request){
    $rep =this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Company');

    $companyId = $request->get('id');
    if ($companyId != null) {
        $rep->delete($companyId);
    } else {
        $rep->deleteAll();
    }
    $response = new Response(null, Response::HTTP_OK);
    return $response;
}
}
```

and so on ...

The only thing that really changes is the entity name ("Customer", "Product", "Company", etc...).

Do you have any ideas how to get rid off all this redundancy and at the same time keep the code readable ?

The first thing that comes to my mind is to create a base class with the delete method logic and just pass entity name as a parameter. Is it ok to do so? For example:

```
class CustomerController extends BaseController{
/**
 * @Route("/customer")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request){
    parent::deleteAction($request, 'AppBundle:Customer');
}
```

Is the above legit solution ? Are there ways to simplify it further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a single controller. Use the route to get the entity classname.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{entityName}/{entityId}")
 * @Route("/{entityName}")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction($entityName, $entityId = null){
    $rep =this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:'.$entityName);
    if ($productId != null) {
        $rep->delete($productId);
    } else {
        $rep->deleteAll();
    }
    $response = new Response(null, Response::HTTP_OK);
    return $response;
}
}
```

Depending on how you build your routes you should have to translate the $entityName string for instance: /entity-name to EntityName or /entity to Entity

Comment: The paranoid programmer would be worried about a user getting permission to run that, and then being able to delete any record in the database by ID

Comment: That's another issue from my point of view. Of courser this enpoints must be secured somehow. At a first step you could build some whitelist of allowed entities to be deleted.

Comment: I have mixed feeling towards this approach. On one hand it greatly reduces the amount of redundant code. On the other hand i think it may violate the 'single responsibility principle'. It also makes code a bit harder to read. Anyway thank you for this idea. One more question: how would you name such controller ?